# What is the role of doc.data() in Firebase?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm building a simple page where I want to render all items from FireStore documents. However, I do not understand what exactly FireStore provides. Is it a promise, object or something different?

Standard functon uses doc.data() to get the information. Can somebody explain why it happens? What exactly doc.data() does?

```
db.collection("cities").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But why it has to be with `console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());`

This is just a way to print, with `console.log()`, the id and field values (through `data()`) of each Firestore `DocumentSnapshot`. As explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/log), `console.log()` can take as parameters "a list of JavaScript objects to output". "The string representations of each of these objects are appended together in the order listed and output".

---

Now to solve your error, you should do as follows (untested):

```
db.collection('teamMember').get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
   querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => { return <TeamCard name={doc.Name} position={doc.position} text={doc.text} src={doc.url} /> });
});
```

because the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method is a method of an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array), and a Firestore [`querySnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot) is not an array. By calling the [`docs`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot?authuser=0#docs) method, you get an Array, that you can use with `map()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and explanation.