# How to efficiently access firestore data within a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

We have a layout within our app for user applications to work events. We list those applications in a v-for loop. However, we really need to reference some additional data on that layout from our users collection. We can achieve this by filtering through our users collection, but it's way too slow.

Here's the code that works, but is so slow (with 20K users) that the site is unusable.

```
<span v-for="u in filteredInfo(props.row)">
                <span v-if="u && u.skills && u.skills.length > 0" style="display:inline;">
                  <v-popover>
                    <i class="fad fa-briefcase"></i>
                    <template slot="popover">
                    <span v-for="z in u.skills">{{z.title}} / </span>
                  </template>
                  </v-popover>
                </span>
              </span>
            </span>
```

Then:

```
filteredInfo(user) {
 return this.users.filter(member => {
    return member.id == user.userId
  })
}
```

If I understand what's happening correctly, each application in my v-for loop has to filter through 20K users to find and load the correct user data... in this case, listing their skills.

To speed up the performance of this layout, wouldn't it be more helpful to call the user data directly? Here's the code I'm trying to get to work, but it doesn't show the data in the v-for loop.

```
filteredInfo(user) {
 fb.usersCollection.doc(user.userId).get()
  .then(doc => {
    console.log(doc.data());
    return doc.data()
  })
}
```

Would my second method (above) speed up the page? If so, what do I need to do to get it working?

Thanks!

Comment: Which `filteredInfo()` function is being used in v-for ?

Comment: The first one works, it's just that the site becomes extremely slow. My idea to make it faster is to use the second code, but it doesn't work.

Comment: In the first function, why not use `find()` assuming that Id is unique?

Comment: LIke this? return this.users.find(member => {
        return member.id == user.userId
      })

Comment: Yes, though do you really need to list all the users at once? Pagination is an option always.

Comment: This is returning an error let found = this.users.find(function (element) {
        return element.id == user.userId
      })
      return found

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'find')

Comment: [Pt 1] I believe the second method would technically be faster when searching for smaller groups of people (since `find` and `filter` iterate over the array while `doc` directly accesses the document in the database), I am curious what error you're getting which causes this to not work (I cannot see where you've mentioned this), and the TypeError when trying to read undefined, I believe that means that `find` simply hasn't found a truthy result to the function you're using... Are you sure `id` and `userId` properties are perfectly equal?

Comment: [Pt 2] Lastly, I would like to ask you how you've set up the Firebase/firestore database, as it's possible that you've not set the doc file name to be that of the userId (it's possible that you've used another unique identifier or have allowed Firestore to randomly generate it's own) because Firestore does not assume that fields called "ID", or anything similar, are the document's identifier

Comment: fabc - yeah that's what I thought too. The data appears in the console.log, but not in  "u in filteredInfo" - maybe I need to adjust that part to make it work?

Comment: Well... doc.data() returns an array, which is mappable (or at least that's what I've understood from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898437/what-is-the-role-of-doc-data-in-firebase) and the firestore docs), so vue shouldn't have a problem with it, but if your console is fine with it but vue isn't, it might be due to the fact that it's returned as a promise, or it might need to be explicitly cast for vue to accept it (as JS auto-casting can be finicky). Other than that, I'm not sure if I can think of another cause at the moment

Comment: Yeah, console.log does return the doc.data(). So maybe the issue isn't getting the data from firebase. Maybe it's getting it to appear within the loop as "u in filteredInfo(user)". I'm not sure how mapping would help, because i don't need to map to a document... we already have the document.

Comment: Hang on, what's in `props.row`? I know vue can be picky with how it iterates over things (multiple roots aren't accepted, so you may need to set `u` to be a value you use inside the loop, so you select `props.row.your_var_here`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is on the size of the query.

You can:

1. Divide the users by a parameter like first letter of the name. This way you would have 20 smaller documents.
2. Use 1 document for each and every user and make queries using:

[Limit and order](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

or

[Paginate](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors)

Comment: Thanks Daniel... just so I understand. We can't access the doc directly (my second code). Instead, we should try and break up our users collection into smaller collections?

Comment: Yes, the problem is making 20.000 queries or 1 query of 20.000 users. the thing is to get a good number of users, (not too many, not too little) on every query, only as you need. If you have one user per document then you can query multiple documents using paginate.